# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli

I am currently experiencing issues with the following script. Upon execution of the script, I do recieve the message "Connection was OK!" however, then I also receive the following messages:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object
>   given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/worldofclucky.net/scripts/auth.php on line
>   11
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/worldofclucky.net/scripts/auth.php on line
>   12

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am far from a PHP/MySQL expert, I wouldn't really even consider my self a novice... I did do some testing and the $username variable is sending from the previous page correctly and when typing `SELECT * FROM forum.mybb_users WHERE username = 'x_clucky' LIMIT 1` into the MySQL client, it gives all of the information you would expect to get. The PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
$username=$_POST["username"];
$hashed_password = md5($_POST['password']); /* For MyBB its $mybb->input['password'] */
$con=mysqli_connect("worldofclucky.net","clucky","CENSORED","forum");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else { echo "Connection was OK!\n";}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mybb_users WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 1",$con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$encrypted_password = md5(md5($row['salt']).$hashed_password);
if($encrypted_password == $row['password']) {
echo "<script>alert('test');</script>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thank you in advanced for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change `mysql` to `mysqli` and use below kind of query. You can't use `mysql` and `mysqli` altogether.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mybb_users WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Answer (score 3):

From a quick look it seems like you are using `mysqli` functions to connect and then `mysql` functions to make the actual query. mysql_* functions are now deprecated.